# CodeBlocks code not working in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, codeblocks

I have code that simply computes the final grade of students. When I run it in CodeBlocks I have no issue. However when I copied it in Visual Studio (wanted to try the IDE), I get the error `vector subscript out of range`.

in `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "info.h"
#include "grade.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "enter name and grades" << std::endl;
    std::vector<info> students;
    info record;
    while (read(std::cin, record))
    {
        students.push_back(record);
    }

    for (std::vector<info>::size_type i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << students[i].name << " ";
        try
        {
            double finalgrade = grade(students[i]); // ERROR
            std::cout << finalgrade;
        }
        catch (std::domain_error e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In `info.h`:

```
#ifndef GUARD_info
#define GUARD_info

#include <string>
#include <vector>


struct info
{
    std::string name;
    double midterm, final;
    std::vector<double> homework;
};

std::istream& read_hw(std::istream&, std::vector<double>&);
std::istream& read(std::istream&, info&);

#endif
```

In `info.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "info.h"

std::istream& read_hw(std::istream& in, std::vector<double>& hw)
{
    if (in)
    {
        hw.clear();
        double x;
        while (in >> x)
        {
            hw.push_back(x);
        }
        in.clear();
    }
    return in;
}

std::istream& read(std::istream& in, info& stu)
{
    in >> stu.name >> stu.midterm >> stu.final;
    read_hw(in, stu.homework);
    return in;
}
```

I have `median.cpp`, `median.h`, `grade.cpp` and `grade.h` files that contain the functions calculating median and final grades (keeping them out as post is getting long).

I think the issue isn't the code itself (as it works fine on CodeBlocks) but its compatibility with different compilers. I haven't found a satisfactory answer yet and would be glad to get input on what might be causing the bug (visual studio builds it without error, but fails when displaying the final grades). Thank you.

EDIT: here are the `grade.cpp`, `grade.h`, `median.cpp` and `median.h` files:

In `grade.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "median.h"
#include "info.h"

double grade(double midterm, double final, double hw)
{
    return 0.2*midterm + 0.4*final + 0.4*hw;
}

double grade(double midterm, double final, const std::vector<double>& hw)
{
    if (hw.size() == 0)
        throw std::domain_error("Student has done no homework.");
    return grade(midterm, final, median(hw));
}

double grade(const info& stu)
{
    return grade(stu.midterm, stu.final, stu.homework);
}
```

In `grade.h`:

```
#ifndef GRADE_H_INCLUDED
#define GRADE_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>
#include "info.h"
#include <stdexcept>

double grade(double, double, double);
double grade(double, double, const std::vector<double>&);
double grade(const info&);

#endif
```

In `median.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

double median(std::vector<double> vec)
{
    if (vec.size() == 0)
        throw std::domain_error("Median of an empty vector.");

    typedef std::vector<double>::size_type vec_sz;
    vec_sz size = vec.size();
    vec_sz mid = size / 2;

    return size % 2 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
}
```

In `median.h`:

```
#ifndef GUARD_median_h
#define GUARD_median_h

#include <vector>

double median(std::vector<double>);

#endif
```

Comment: What value do you see if you step through with the debugger?

Comment: VS makes lots more checks than codeworks to help you to find nasty bugs. What's the definition of grade() ?

Comment: Yes, you should step through the grade() function and make sure the homework vector is being indexed correctly.

Comment: @Christophe thanks, I've added the definition of grade() as an edit.

Comment: @ben I get a "debug assertion failed" pop up window right after the first student's name is printed. The windows indicates "vector subscript out of range", however when I change the call to grade() for a call to students[i].midterm, it prints the midterm grade with no issue (so the vector subscript doesn't seem to be out of range). I've added the definition of grade(), thanks for your input ben.

Comment: Ok, now could you show us `median()` ?

Comment: @Christophe thank you for your patience, I added median().

Comment: In median.cpp, what happens if `vec.size()` is 1? Wouldn't that cause `vec[mid-1]` to exceed the valid index range?

Comment: @MarkU My understanding is that if `vec.size() = 1`, then `mid = size / 2 = 0` because size_type gives the lower integer when the result is not an integer. Therefore `median()` would return `vec[0]` which will be the only value in the vector.

Comment: @MarkU Ignore my latest comment you are 100% right I wrote `return size % 2 ?` instead of `return size % 2 == 0 ?`. I have made the modification and it now runs fine on Visual Studio, thank you so much

Comment: MarkU is correct.  If `vec.size()` is 1, then `mid = size / 2 = 0`, as you said.  But then `size % 2 is 1`, which evaluates to true, and executes `(vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2`.  Which means `vec[mid - 1]` is out of range (since mid = 0)

Comment: @ben you are 100% correct in backing MarkU, this was indeed the source of the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly wrote in my median() function

```
return size % 2 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
```

when I should have written

```
return size % 2 == 0 ? (vec[mid] + vec[mid - 1]) / 2 : vec[mid];
```

Thanks MarkU!